# Daylight Saving Moment.js issues on Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, momentjs

I have a function, to get all days in a range:

```js
function getDates(inicio, fim, isMoment = false) {
            inicio = moment.utc(inicio); //new Date(inicio);
            fim = moment.utc(fim); //new Date(fim);
            var dias = [];
            var atual = inicio;
            while(atual.utc() <= fim){
                dias.push(atual.format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
                //dias.push(moment.utc(atual.format("YYYY-MM-DD")));
                //dias.push(atual.clone().tz("America/Sao_Paulo"));//America/Sao_Paulo
                atual.add(1, "d");
            }
            if(isMoment){
                var i;
                var result = [];
                    for(i = 0; i < dias.length; i++){
                    //console.log(i +" - " +dias[i]);
                    result.push(moment(dias[i]));
                    }
                return result;
            }
            return dias;
        }
//Tested with:
var a = getDates("2016-01-01", "2016-12-31", true);
console.log(a[365].toDate());
```

```html
<script src="//momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

This works fine on Mozilla Firefox, returning all days correctly , but on Google Chrome and Opera(I think there is something on Blink and Chromium JS Engine) even using UTC, the result is prior day at 22h(Brazilian Summer Time):

Chrome/Opera Result: `Fri Dec 30 2016 22:00:00 GMT-0200 (Horário brasileiro de verão)`

Firefox Result: `Date 2016-12-31T00:00:00.000Z`

Is it an Issue on V8 or SpiderMonkey - Who is wright, V8 to always use real time or SM to use developer's given date? Is there a way to make all process ignoring  daylight saving?

Comment: you may want to change `http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js` to `//momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js` in the snippet so it works http or https without a mixed content warning - it's OK I edited for you

Comment: No messages, just the results above. Interesting, that Google Chrome and Opera have same behavior - return as daylight, different from Firefox - return exact time. I just need a moment object as recieved in Firefox.

Comment: In the snippet, i only made this to get the .js file, on my code it's locally.

Comment: I understand, but my edit makes it runnable here

Comment: please try changing `result.push(moment(dias[i]));` to `result.push(moment(dias[i]), 'yyyy-m-d');`

Comment: by the way, I get `"2016-12-30T13:00:00.000Z"` in both firefox and chrome

Comment: In Chrome i've got `Sun Dec 25 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0200 (Local Daylight Time)` - Every Moment object created, has right date on `_d` property, but on `.toDate()` it returns same result

Comment: If the date object holds the correct value, why does it matter what the string representation is?

Comment: It also makes sense to reverse the logic somewhat, so you don't stringify the objects, just to turn them back into objects, like this -> https://jsfiddle.net/sexrznut/1/

Comment: How do i get this? i need to compare with a Moment array.

Comment: If that array contains moment objects, you'd use the `isSame` method to compare two moment objects -> https://jsfiddle.net/sexrznut/2/

Comment: Alternatively you'd compare the timestamps *(hint: getTime())*, you do not want to compare the string representations of the objects.

Comment: Can i compare two Moment dates using `isSame()` even they're in different timezomes - ie.: Brazilian DST is same to UCT - constructing with same string?